# Not getting value of attribute(Magento)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I have created an attribute named as 'specialtext' for every product.But not getting value of this specialtext field in frontend.Any idea?

Comment: Make sure that either 1) Your product is loaded or 2) You have use on product listing is set to yes...

Answer (score 2):

Get attribute value for PLAIN TEXT, TEXTAREA or DATE type attribute:

```
$attribute_value = $product->getShirtSize(); //for shirt_size attribute
```

Get value from SELECT, MULTISELECT, DROPDOWN or YES/NO attributes:

```
$attribute_value = $product->getAttributeText($attribute_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

**text or textarea field**

For these attributes use this:

```
// specify the attribute code
$attributeCode = 'name';

// build and filter the product collection
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('notnull' => true))
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);

// get all distinct attribute values
$usedAttributeValues = array_unique($products->getColumnValues($attributeCode));
```

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show newly created product attribute you need to add it to the "attribute sets".
Have you added this attribute to attribute set?